# Why does ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString return []?

Tags: java, spring, jackson

The below always returns a value of []
I've tried with both public and private params but no matter what its not working.
I'm intending to loop over an ArrayList of objects and convert them to an array of json for returning but it won't even convert a single object.

I've tried removing the constructor and just using setters to set the params after creating the object. When I println the object I get `QuizTable{id='foo', quizTitle='bar', ownerId='fizz'}` so it does look to be creating the object

```
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public ArrayList<String> getAll(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        QuizTable quiz = new QuizTable("foo", "bar", "fizz");
        String toJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(newQuiz);
        System.out.println(toJson);
        return toJson;
    }
```

```
public class QuizTable extends ArrayList<QuizTable> {

    public String id;
    public String quizTitle;
    public String ownerId;

    public QuizTable(String id, String title, String owner) {
        this.id = id;
        this.quizTitle = title;
        this.ownerId = owner;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String everything(){
        return this.id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public String asJson(){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getQuizTitle() {
        return quizTitle;
    }

    public void setQuizTitle(String quizTitle) {
        this.quizTitle = quizTitle;
    }

    public String getOwnerId() {
        return ownerId;
    }

    public void setOwnerId(String ownerId) {
        this.ownerId = ownerId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "QuizTable{" +
                "id='" + id + '\'' +
                ", quizTitle='" + quizTitle + '\'' +
                ", ownerId='" + ownerId + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `extends ArrayList<QuizTable> `? What is the use?
Have you tried your code after removing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are extending `ArrayList<QuizTable>` for no apparent reason.
So your class `QuizTable` has extended properties of an `ArrayList` class.
You are getting an empty array as JSON because of extending this class because ObjectMapper is converting it as an `ArrayList`.

Let's look at an example here:

I have created a `TestClass`

```
public class TestClass extends ArrayList<TestClass> {

    private final String firstName;

    public TestClass(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
}
```

Lets create another class:

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TestClass quiz = new TestClass("foo");
        try {
            String toJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(quiz);
            System.out.println(toJson);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException j) {
            System.out.println("E");
        }
    }

}
```

The output will be:
`[]`

But as soon as you remove the `extends ArrayList<TestClass>` or use `extends Object` or don't extend anything:

```
public class TestClass {

    private final String firstName;

    public TestClass(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

}
```

You get your desired output:
`{"firstName":"foo"}`

Comment: Nicely done! 1+

Comment: tysm, can't believe i didn't see that!